# Import from MSSQL to Excel when the data contains embedded line breaks

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to export a sql query (MS SQL 2014) into excel 2010. The problem is column values contain line breaks, so the remaining data gets copied to the next line in excel. Is there a way to get rid of this? Keeping the column as is? or maybe encapsulating the column so the sql considers it as one column and ignores the line breaks?

Here is my SQL Query:

```
select * from tbl_case 
where (casenature not like '%<strong>%' 
and casenature not like '%<br />%' 
and casenature like '%from:%') 
and userid in (select employeelogin from tbl_employees where riding='15010')
```

Comment: How do you make the import?

Comment: I have a textarea in which the users add stuff, So they can add stuff by copy pasting the emails or whatever they want.

Comment: How is the last statement relevant? Do you mean to say you copy-paste the data into Excel from somewhere?

Comment: I mean, I have a form on which the user can add new cases. for which I have different fields, for the casenature to be precise, I have a textarea in which users can add anything, for this case they have added emails which contain line breaks :(

Comment: This is all irrelevant. The question is about the step when the data gets from mssql to excel. How does this particular step happen?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev You asked me about the import, I am saying that i have a website, through which the users make the entries and i save that data into a table(tbl_case). Now I am trying to export that table to excel, that's where I am facing problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64653/discussion-between-shashank-and-ivan-pozdeev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine if I use the normal way to import data from MSSQL to Excel which is: in Excel, `Data->From other sources->SQL server`.

To import data resulting from an arbitrary SQL query:

- At the last step of the wizard (where you select the range), press `Properties...`
- In the resulting `Connection properties` window:

  - `Definition->Command type` - `SQL`
  - In the `Command text` field, write your query

Comment: It allows me to create a connection, but doesn't allow me to enter my query. Moreover asks me to select only one table :(

Comment: Worked as a charm! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace enter keys with space in select statement, and then export to Excel

Comment: I dont want that, I want to keep the Enter keys intact, and the whole text should come in that column

Comment: The original question implies HTML, a context where newlines are replaced by spaces all over the place during rendering.  This answer seems reasonable and easy to implement.

Comment: But it will lose the formatting that the users have added into the data.